# What is purpose of label attribute in JSF commandbutton?

Tags: jsf

What is the purpose of the label attribute in a JSF Command button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very well spotted. It has really no meaningful purpose on a [`<h:commandButton>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html).

This attribute is supposed to be present in [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) components such as [`<h:inputText>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputText.html) only. It's then exactly that value which will then be used in the first message format placeholder `{0}` of validation/conversion messages so that it shows up like so with e.g. `label="Username"`:

> Username: Value is required

If the `label` attribute is omitted, it would default to the component's client ID which is often less friendly readable towards the enduser with autogenerated IDs and `:` separator and so on like so

> formId:inputId: Value is required

This attribute was introduced in JSF 1.2. I think that the mistake of the JSF developer/implementer was to specify the new attrubute for JSF components which generate HTML `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` elements, not specifically on JSF compnents which extend from [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html). This attribute is namely (correctly) absent on [`<h:commandLink>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandLink.html) which belongs to the same [`UICommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html) family as [`<h:commandButton>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html).

I've reported it as [issue 2365](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2365).